# Убрать устаревшую информацию из описания привилегии "Постоянный пользователь"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, привилегии

На странице описания привилегии ["Постоянный пользователь"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) присутствует информация, которая на текущий момент уже является устаревшей. В частности речь про так называемую "расширенную карточку пользователя". Насколько я вижу, теперь она работает и для участников без 1000 баллов репутации. На англоязычных сайтах страница описания привилегии уже не содержит информацию о расширенной карточке пользователя. Примеры:

- [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)
- [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Ну и сам вопрос о том, что это уже работает для всех: [Can we make the "expanded user card" privilege universal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334941/339911)

Comment: А я все ломал се голову — что за карточка такая...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor карточная система, как в Советском Союзе. Продержалась чуть дольше, правда.

Comment: Хех. Смешно. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor смешно для тех, кто не застал.